How to implement reaction buttons in BotFramework-WebChat to send reactions to the Bot on Azure
I'm currently working on a chatbot using the NPM package BotFramework-WebChat with Typescript. The backend is hosted on Azure. I've come across a scenario where I want to implement reaction buttons (like thumbs up, thumbs down, etc.) for each message in the WebChat. The goal is to allow users to send reactions back to the bot, similar to how it's done in Microsoft Teams.
While exploring the BotFramework-WebChat GitHub documentation and samples, I found an example suggesting that this is possible. However, I'm facing some challenges:

The types that the documentation references don't seem to exist in the current version of the library. (related GitHub issues: 3866, 5246)
The mock bot provided in the sample doesn't work as expected, making it difficult to understand the implementation.

According to the documentation it should be possible to create a function like this:
  const postActivity = usePostActivity();

  const handleUpvoteButton = useCallback(() => {
    postActivity({
      type: 'messageReaction',
      reactionsAdded: [{ activityID, helpful: 1 }],
    });
  }, [activityID, postActivity]);

But I got these type errors:
Type '"messageReaction"' is not assignable to type '"event" | "conversationUpdate" | "invoke" | "message" | "typing"'
'reactionsAdded' does not exist in type 'WebChatActivity'
My questions are:

Is it possible to implement reaction buttons in BotFramework-WebChat that send reactions back to the bot on Azure?
If it's possible, can someone provide guidance or an example of how to correctly implement this feature?
Is this functionality limited to Microsoft Teams, or can it be fully realized in a web-based chat experience using WebChat?


Accepting / upvoting an answer serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" and upvote it. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Unfortunately, I am unable to repro the exact error you are receiving when testing your code. However, your implementation of handleUpvoteButton doesn't align with the sample's code. It should be setup like this:
const addMessageReaction = helpful => {
  postActivity( {
    type: 'messageReaction',
    reactionsAdded: [ { type: helpful === 1 ? 'ThumbsUp' : 'ThumbsDown' } ],
    replyToId: activityID,
  } );
};

const handleUpvoteButton = useCallback( () => {
  addMessageReaction( 1 );
}, [ activityID, postActivity ] );

Or, if you weren't wanting to extrapolate the code for addMessageReaction into its own function, then the code should look like this:
const handleUpvoteButton = useCallback( () => {
  (helpful => {
    postActivity( {
      type: 'messageReaction',
      reactionsAdded: [ { type: helpful === 1 ? 'ThumbsUp' : 'ThumbsDown' } ],
      replyToId: activityID,
    } );
  })()
}, [ activityID, postActivity ] );

This implementation works for me, so try this out and see if it works for you.

Yes, you are right, the code in the documentation is a bit different regarding how to pass the type of the reaction.
But my issue is already that the value 'messageReaction' does not exist in the TypeScript type definition of WebChatActivity.
Additionally there is no parameter 'reactionsAdded' available at all in the type definition.
Is it just a type issue and works with plain JavaScript?

Correct, it is just a type issue. Generally-speaking, Web Chat allows for the creation of custom activity types so you should be able to get away with extending WebChatActivity to include messageReaction, or something similar. If you feel strongly that it should be included, then I'd suggest creating a feature request on the BotFramework-WebChat repo. The developer will (eventually) weigh in on the request.
